# How do I prevent the http client from TLS renegotiation?

Tags: go, tls1.2

I'm trying to connect to a server that wants to do some TLS renegotiation, however the current Go TLS client does not support renegotiation.  Is there a way that I can force it to not renegotiate?  I've tried setting the min/max versions to TLS 1.2 and setting PreferServerCipherSuites to true, but still no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe that the spec says the server can force renegotiation at any time, so you may be out of luck. You might have to contact the people running the server you're trying to connect to and see if they're willing to not require that.

Answer (score 3):

The problem has been solved in this [issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/5742) with this [commit](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/af125a5193c75dd59307fcf1b26d885010ce8bfd) but you have to wait for Go version 1.7 to be released

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all that answered, but it looks like I messed up a conditional statement that prevented TLS from being configured, so everything I was trying didn't work.  smh...

I ended up getting it to work by taking the version of common.go in the commit, replacing the original version that game with go 1.6.2, and rebuilt the standard library.  I'll leave how to do that as an exercise to the reader as it's not something I recommend doing.  However, it looks like everything is working, so hopefully 1.7 will be out soon.

Now, I can't recall right now if I got this to work, but if someone else is in the same boat, I believe you can set the Min/Max TLS version to the same version and set PreferServerCipherSuites to true.  This may work, but please keep childofsoong's comment in mind.

Comment: I've been using Go 1.7 from git for quite a while now, and it's stable and much faster, YMMV.